# Is there a way to get the data on google bigquery by using a formula?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to get the data from a table of bigquery by using the select query, and I need to calculate the values extracted. Actually, after getting the data, the calculation will be easy and simple, but I hope to get the values calculated by using some technique that I really want to know. The sample data table as following:

table: sample
[{name: 'A' , value: 45 },
 
{name: 'B', value: 53 },
 
{name: 'C', value:84 },
 
{name: 'D', value: 65}]

What I want to do is name A's value, (name  B's value + name C's value)/2 and name  D's value with query. The important thing is (B's value + C's value)/2. Can I get the data with this like formula by sending the query to bigquery?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A, (B+C)/2 AS BC, D
FROM your_table
```